# Best way to hard render react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I'm fetching a list of post from a local server and then updated it with a form, but after submitting the list doesn't update, it must be reloaded to update the list. I tried  adding a counter state and place it on my second parameter in UseEffect, it worked but sometimes it won't.
Is there a best way to keep up to date my list with the server without reloading?

here is my code

```
function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getPosts();
  }, []);

  const getPosts = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get("/posts");
    const { data } = response;
    setPosts(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        component={() => <Posts posts={posts} getPosts={getPosts} />}
      />
      <Route exact path="/add" render={() => <Form  />} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const Posts = ({ posts, getPosts }) => {
  console.log("Render POSTS");
  // const { posts } = React.useContext(postsContext);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {posts.map((post, idx) => (
        <Post
          title={post.title}
          description={post.description}
          key={idx}
          id={post._id}
          getPosts={getPosts}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Form = ({ getPosts }) => {
  const [title, titleChange, resetTitle] = InputHooks();
  const [description, descriptionChange, resetDescription] = InputHooks();
  // const { renderToggle } = React.useContext(postsContext);

  async function submitForm() {
    const response = await axios.post("/posts", { title, description });
    const { data } = response;
    console.log(data.message);
  }
  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
        <input
          name="title"
          id="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={titleChange}
        ></input>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
        <textarea
          name="description"
          id="description"
          value={description}
          onChange={descriptionChange}
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={async (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          submitForm();
          resetTitle();
          resetDescription();
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
```

Comment: You should get posts every time after adding a new post. To do so, you need to use Redux or Context to communicate between two pages.

Comment: already tried, i executed getPosts function after submitting post. but still, the posts just stays there. have to reload.

Comment: it's finally working, i executed getPosts after submitPost, but this time i'm using await on submitPost to really wait that function to finish before getPosts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer guys, I finally solved it using async function. I use await on `submitPost` and followed by `getPosts()`, so each submit I will await until the `submit` completes and then `getPost`. My first time mistake was putting the `await` on `getPosts`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this:  `React.useEffect(() => { getPosts(); }, [posts]);` we place posts in here in useEffect so that whenever that variable changes, it will re-render the whole component.

Comment: Already tried, it causes infinite loop on useEffect because the array references keep changing

Comment: My apologies! Thanks for giving it a try.